# Get records happening on a particular date from mysql

Tags: mysql

First of all this is weird, I couldn't even find a perfect title for this question. Here is the scenario :

This is my event table structure :

```
id  start_date  end_date
1   2014-10-13  2014-10-24
2   2014-10-16  2014-10-18
3   2014-11-17  2014-11-20
```

Now my user input a particular date. For example **2014-10-20**. He need all the events going on that particular date. How to achieve this ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
  from event_table
 where date'2014-10-20' >= start_date
   and date'2014-10-20' <= end_date
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from your_table
where '2014-10-20' between start_date and end_date
```